# How to add inline style to body using vuejs component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am a vue.js learner and I have started a couple of days ago so there is still some stuff I may not comprehend well. I am trying to design a dropdown menu that displays when the user clicks on the 3 dots, now I am unable to make the background of the dropdown menu scroll, so How can I add an inline overflow style when the user opens the dropdown menu. Hope I was able to describe well what I want and will be pleased for anyone who would like to help me, thanks ahead

```js
// CREATE THE DOM COMPONENT
    Vue.component('mob-menu', {
        data() {
            return { checked: false}
        },
        methods: {
            check() { this.checked = !this.checked; }
        }
    });
    
    vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        showModal: false,
    },
    });
```

```css
.m__header__icon {
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 24px;
    position: relative;
}

.m__header__icon__cart-quantity {
    margin-left: 0;
    left: 15px;
    top: -10px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ef3b42;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: absolute;
}

.m__dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -1px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
}

.m__dropdown-menu a:not(:last-child) {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: #f1f1f1 1px solid;
}

.m__dropdown-menu__item {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 16px;
}

.m__dropdown-menu__item img {
    margin: 0;
}

.m__dropdown-menu__item__title {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0 8px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}

.cover{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 16;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<body :style="'overflow: hidden'">
</div id="app">
<div class="m__container">
<mob-menu inline-template>
    <div>
    <div class="m__header" :class="[checked ? 'm__header_dropdown': 'm__header_close' ]">
        <div class="m__header_icons">
         <span @click="check" class="m__header__icon">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#858585" width="24" height="24">
                <path d="M12 17.5a2.5 2.5 0 010 5 2.5 2.5 0 010-5zm0-8a2.5 2.5 0 010 5 2.5 2.5 0 010-5zm0-8a2.5 2.5 0 010 5 2.5 2.5 0 010-5z"></path>
            </svg>
        </span>
        </div>
          <div v-if="checked" class="m__dropdown-menu">
        <a href="/" class="router-link-active">
            <div class="m__dropdown-menu__item">
                <div class="m__dropdown-menu__item__title">Home</div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="/categories" class="">
            <div class="m__dropdown-menu__item">
                <div class="m__dropdown-menu__item__title">Kategori</div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a to="/pages/official-store" href="/pages/official-store">
            <div class="m__dropdown-menu__item">
                <div class="m__dropdown-menu__item__title">Official Store</div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="/account" class="">
            <div class="m__dropdown-menu__item">
                <div class="m__dropdown-menu__item__title">Akun</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div v-if="checked" class="cover"></div>
    </div>
 </mob-menu>
 </div>
 </body>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As usual css, as string: `<body style="overflow: hidden">`
The colon only, if you pass a value from a var, func etc. which returns something:

```
<body :style="{'overflow': valueFromVar }">
```

Hope that helps.